# Django : get the last item of manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django, django-models

With these models :

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_send = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    emeteur = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,related_name="+")

    class Meta :
        abstract = True


class MessagePerso(Message) :
    read_at = models.DateTimeField(("read at"), null=True, blank=True)

class Conversation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,related_name="CreatorConversation")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,related_name="RecipientConversation")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(MessagePerso)
```

**So, for each Conversation I want the text of the last MessagePerso created (ManyToManyField in Conversation) and others informations.**

So for now, I have this :

```
def .. :
    u = request.user
    conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(Q(creatorr=u)|Q(destinataire=u)).annotate(nbMsg=Count('messages'),date=Max('messages__date_send')).order_by('date','id')
```

I don't have the the text of last message created for each Conversation, how makes it ?

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order your data by a `date_send` field ascending as follow:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_send = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    emeteur = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,related_name="+")

    class Meta :
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['date_send'] # default ordrer while fetching data
```

Than for each conversation's messages you fetch the last using [.last()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#last):

```py
def .. :
    u = request.user
    conversation_id_list = Conversation.objects.filter(Q(creatorr=u)|Q(destinataire=u)).values_list('id', flat=True)
    message_list = list(()
    for id in conversation_id_list:
        last_message = MessagePerso.objects.filter(conversation_id=id).last()
        message_list.append(last_message)
        print(last_message.text)
```

if the number of conversation is kind of big and you want to minimize db queries you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related)

```py
def .. :
    u = request.user
    conversation_list = Conversation.objects.filter(Q(creatorr=u)|Q(destinataire=u)).preftech_related('messages')
    messages_dict =dict()
    for conversation in conversation_list:
        messages_dict.update({
            converstaion.id: conversation.messages.all()
        })
    last_message_list = list()
    for conversation_id, message_list in messages_dict.items():
        if message_list:
          last_message = messages_dict.get(conversation_id)[len(message_list) -1:]
          last_message_list.append(last_message)
          print(last_message.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! But I have decided not show the text of last message... I recorded your solution ;) I hope it's works